# Optimize Font Awesome for only used classes

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

I am using Font Awesome Sass file https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/blob/master/sass/font-awesome.sass to make it **_font-awesome.sass** so I can `@import` in my Sass project. I am also using http://middlemanapp.com/ to convert **Sass** to **Css**. Questions:

1. Is there a way to bring only **used icon classes** into my converted .css? Because right now it carried all classes from **_font-awesome.sass**
2. **BONUS:** Is it possible to **recompile** the fonts somehow with **used icon classes** to make it smaller on production use?

If I can get some tips on #1 above, that would be awesome enough.

Thanks.

Comment: csslint will help find the unused classes, so at least you won't have to do that manually. automating...you would probably have to implement yourself, but it's also on github so you can roll your own

Comment: How do you expect Sass to know which classes you're using?  This website can generate custom font files from a number of icon fonts:  http://fontello.com/

Comment: @cimmanon why don't you post your answer below and I will accept it? I have been using fontello.com and it was what I looked for.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Sass has no idea what classes you are actually using.  This is something you will have to manually trim down yourself.  Open up the provided .scss file and hack out anything you don't need.

Editing the font file itself to eliminate unneeded glyphs requires a 3rd party application to do so and is beyond the scope of this question.

---

[Fontello](http://fontello.com/) is an online web service that can do all of this for you.  It lets you mix and match between multiple icon font collections to create the perfect font file for your project.  In addition to the customized font file, it provides multiple .css files containing styles already generated for you (changing the extension to .scss will allow you to import them into your existing Sass project).

Comment: fontello changes the class name of the icons automatically - is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Fontello have some missing icons. No React, JavaScript, Node.js, Java, for example

Answer (score 45):

fontello is very good but [IcoMoon](http://icomoon.io/app) is even more awesome.

Comment: IcoMoon lets you import your own font. Fontello doesn't

Comment: I found that IcoMoon only supports a subset of Font Awesome icons.

Comment: @TonyO'Hagan Maybe you can import Font Awesome font file from your local file system.

Comment: IcoMoon have missing icons. No React, JavaScript, Node.js, for example

Comment: Just a FYI but when Font Awesome icons are imported into IcoMoon some of the icons might not always be centered - this seems to be a problem with the font file rather than IcoMoon because if you open the Font Awesome font file in Inkscape you can see that some of the icons are misaligned (although they display correctly when output to the browser). The solution seems to be to use IcoMoon's glyph editing controls to reduce the canvas width and center the icon.

Answer (score 11):

You can now subset icons from Font-awesome for production use. There is now an official subsetting tool called **[icnfnt](https://github.com/johnsmclay/icnfnt)**, which allows you to pick and package just the icons you need from the current version of Font-awesome (v3.0.2).

The custom download also includes all CSS, LESS, SCSS and SASS code!

Comment: I don't know if that tool would qualify as official

Answer (score 7):

I use LESS and not SASS so you might have to adapt your implementation.

Environment:

- Font awesome 4.5.0 (current version)
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- bash

Use this to generate the list of Unicode character numbers that you need:

```
fa_icons="globe|vimeo|youtube|facebook|twitter|google-plus"
for code in $(egrep "^@fa-var-($fa_icons):" less/font-awesome/variables.less | cut -d ':' -f 2 | sed -e 's/^ "\\//' | sed -e 's/";/,/' | sort ); do echo -n $code; done
```

You then use this with FontSquirrel in the expert mode where you select custom subsetting: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

In Unicode ranges enter the comma separated values from above.

Then to remove unnecessary stuff from the CSS:

```
egrep "@fa-var-($fa_icons);" less/font-awesome/icons.less
```

You'll need to open `less/font-awesome/icons.less` and paste the output from the grep into the file.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the sass can certainly be jiggled a little to make the selectors `%` based so they are extendable only. Once this is done, classes can be made to match the wanted icons, and then can `@extend` the font-awesome classes.

Personally, I do this, and don't actually use the classes in the markup, and just use selectors to the relevant elements and `@extend` them with these classes.

Example:

```
// _icons.scss
%#{$fa-css-prefix}-glass:before { content: $fa-var-glass; }
...

// _core.scss
%#{$fa-css-prefix} {
    ...
}
```

Then in your scss

```
a.search {
    @extend %fa;
    @extend %fa-search;
}
```

Et voila.

Answer (score 2):

[Fontastic](http://app.fontastic.me/) worked for me (it was listed on [Font Awesome github page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Customize-Font-Awesome)). Select glyphs that you need and download them as a new custom font. Excellent tool.

Comment: Fontastic requires you to register upfront to demonstrate anything

Comment: That was not the case a year ago as far as I remember. Sad.

Comment: Just use [mailinator](http://mailinator.com) to create an account there. It worked perfectly for exporting the icons.

Answer (score 1):

Iconmoon worked for me. I used it by importing the svg file from font-awesome thus ensuring I get the icons I want and not just the ones available on their site. Also this link helped me with the integration of the new icons
https://tonyxu.io/posts/2018/use-icomoon-to-reduce-fontawesome-size/

Answer (score 1):

All the other optimization tools here are browser-based. If you're looking for something that can be easily automated and run locally, [`fontite`](https://gitlab.com/antonok/fontite) might be the best option.

You'd list the icons you're using in the TOML config file. It will create the CSS with just those classes, as well as packing only those icons into your final font file. You can even combine icons from Font Awesome Brands, Font Awesome Solid, etc. into the same CSS and font files.

Answer (score 1):

I think [subset-iconfont](https://github.com/dzhuang/subset-iconfont) meet exactly your needs. The purpose of this package is to subset from several icon font packages and use the latest fontawesome css/scss styles. To fit your need, you can do it in a few lines:

```
npm install --save-dev subset-iconfont @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

then

```js
import { FaFreeProvider } from 'subset-iconfont';

const fa = new FaFreeProvider (['plus', 'clock', '500px'], {
  formats: ['ttf', 'woff2'],
});

fa.makeFonts('./outputDir').then((result) => {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

Then in folder `./outputDir` find the result, open the generated `index.html` to see  how to use it.

Besides, you can also subset from some other iconfont packages and use the subset result in FontAwesome style.

P.S., I'm the author of the package.