# How to install only required fonts from Font Awesome?

Tags: font-awesome

I would to use a couple of icons from Font Awesome.

I see that we can download the entire font-awesome directory and use simple code like `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` and use `fa-camera-retro` to display the icons.

Is it possible for me to download only the fonts I will be using?

For the above example if I am using only `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>`, `fa-camera-retro`, I would like to reduce the directory size by only using the files related to this icon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331525/optimize-font-awesome-for-only-used-classes

Answer (score 78):

Perhaps this helps:
[fontello](http://fontello.com/)

fontello lets you choose your icons and compile your own version

Comment: Useful but with Font-Awesome run until version 4.7

Comment: This is what I was looking for. The fontawesome file size is reduced from 166KB to 6KB since I am using only 25 icons.

Answer (score 37):

With [Icomoon](https://icomoon.io/app/), you can choose a subset of icons and create your own custom icon font, and it's not just for Font Awesome, they have other libraries.

Comment: Have missing icons. No React, JavaScript, Node.js for example

Comment: Works perfectly, nice app. Had a lot of icons and the SVG package I downloaded was intuitive to use and included example code.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I reduced default fa css size from 27KB to 6KB and woff2 from 65KB to 13KB. If you have `core web vitals` in mind and want to improve your page load speed, then you should look into this.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to propose an alternative solution since there're only a few answers provided here.
I faced the same issue and found that the easiest solution was to simply use the svg version. Make sure to provide a height or width dimension though!

```html
<img class="my-fa-icon" src="/assets/css/fontawesome-free-svgs/brands/facebook-f.svg">
```

```css
.my-fa-icon {
  width: 1rem; /** Required */
}
```

I know it's not *exactly* what the question demands, but it's simple & works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Icongram](https://icongr.am/fontawesome). It helps you to import required icons from various libraries like FontAwesome, Material etc. If you need more customization not sure if it will help you but it can cater to most use cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think [subset-iconfont](https://github.com/dzhuang/subset-iconfont) meet exactly your needs. The purpose of this package is to subset from several icon font packages and use the latest fontawesome (6.1.1) css/scss styles. To fit your need, you can do it in a few lines:

```
npm install --save-dev subset-iconfont @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

then

```js
import { FaFreeProvider } from 'subset-iconfont';

const fa = new FaFreeProvider (['plus', 'clock', '500px'], {
  formats: ['ttf', 'woff2'],
});

fa.makeFonts('./outputDir').then((result) => {
  console.log('Done!');
});
```

Then in folder `./outputDir` find the result, open the generated `index.html` to see  how to use it.

Besides, you can also subset from some other iconfont packages and use the subset result in FontAwesome style.

P.S., I'm the author of the package.