# How do I "pull-out" only the dozen icons I actually use?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, font-awesome

I have an angular project that is built using grunt which uses maybe a dozen icons from font-awesome. Currently, I'm including and thus distributing the entire font-awesome library. Is there a way to "pull-out" only the icons I actually use (preferably as part of the build process)?

I've seen the icomoon app, and that seems to give me the result I want, but it's a manual process to update when icon usage changes.

Comment: I have been waiting for an answer to this question. I tried writing a grunt task to do that but couldn't get it to work. I hope there is a solution to that problem cause this is why I stopped using font-awesome and started to rely purely on SVGs

Comment: What do you actually win by doing that?

Comment: I guess eflat wants to reduce the size of the files all users have to download when visiting his website.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install only required fonts from Font Awesome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193404/how-to-install-only-required-fonts-from-font-awesome)

Comment: As in the post referenced by @LifeQuery you could use http://fontello.com/ to choose a subset of fonts from several font libraries and download a zip containing font files and CSS.

Comment: Yes, right now font-awesome accounts for more than half of my download. Thanks for the leads to fontello, especially as there is a grunt-fontello which may be out of date but hopefully tweakable to fix. It may be a couple days before I can try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use [Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG](https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG) to get individual SVG files for each Font Awesome icon.

```
font-awesome-svg-png --color black --sizes 128 --no-png
```

Then using [grunt-webfont](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-webfont), combine the icons of your choosing (from the SVGs generated in the previous step) into a custom webfont.

For example, if you only want to include icons which have **angle-** keyword in your webfont, then the grunt task would be like -

```
webfont: {
    icons: {
        src: 'black/svg/angle-*.svg',
        dest: 'build/fonts'
    }
}
```