# FontAwsome, is it possible to only load one or two icons onto a site without a full CDN load or full local script?

Tags: fonts, font-awesome, cdn

With Font Awesome, is it possible to only load one or two icons onto a site without a full CDN load or full local script? I was hoping to find this possible to save bandwidth for a site that only uses two fa icons.

Comment: The font and CSS files are required. You can edit the CSS and remove unused "fa" classes.

Comment: Thanks Eli, this is actually somewhat of the route I am looking to go. As Anthony stated, it would be a LOT of work to edit source font file so I am guessing cutting down the size of FA CSS may be the simplest answer.

Comment: Perhaps related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34552353/how-do-i-pull-out-only-the-dozen-icons-i-actually-use

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a simple way of doing this. Most of the file size for Font Awesome comes from the fonts used to render the icons: https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-less/tree/master/assets/fonts/font-awesome. So you'd need to actually modify these files and the CSS files referencing them, which would likely not be worth the effort.

If you're only interested in one or two icons FA isn't much of a benefit here anyhow. A much simpler and space-efficient approach would be to use simple PNG or vector graphics for the two icons you need.

If you want the exact FA icons, then you might find this tool useful: http://fa2png.io/. There's also a project converting the FA icons to PNG/SVG here: https://github.com/encharm/Font-Awesome-SVG-PNG.

Comment: Thanks. It may have taken me forever to find these links above, so your help on StackO is much appreciated. I might take the time to to modify the FA files just for kicks and here is why: My main reason to use FA Icons was to avoid images. If I have hundreds of useful UI "direction related icon images" then I wanted to cut down on my bandwidth by using FA. YET, my site was being used as a **CDN** where some Asian countries piped my FA and my Bootstrap from host! _This may be a whole new topic of its own._ So having minimal files size would have been (a) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Using png image IS a better answer, just to save butchering of the source files. Although I really like the quality and portability of fa-icons so I was hoping this was possible just to preserve the CSS flexibility of the FA icons over any image [non]flexibility from selectors such as resize, position, scale, color, font-weight, transition or any other CSS trick one would want to utilize. An FA icon would love the flexibility of CSS and media calls.