# Font awesome only two icons

Tags: font-awesome

I am using font awesome 5 icons on my website. But I only need 2 or 3 of them. So webpage gets all css from fontawesome cdn. This slows my website. Is there any way to select which icons I want use and only download their css?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install only required fonts from Font Awesome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23193404/how-to-install-only-required-fonts-from-font-awesome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a simple & easy way to extract the required icons using [icongram](https://icongr.am/fontawesome). You can download the required SVGs into your code & host locally. The shortcoming is you may not get the required customization (size, height, width) sometimes but still useful for most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

Download it, delete everything you don't need, upload it with your site.