# How can I export only one character from ttf / woff file to avoid load unnecessary file size?

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, truetype, woff

I use only one or two character on my website from ttf / woff file. I want to create new font file for 2 used character to avoid load unnecessary file size.I want to make faster my website.So, I must create new font file which contains only used characters.

How Can I do it?

I use linux, ubuntu. I know wordpress,php. Also I have internet.You can give any solution about these.

Comment: There are free services/apps that help to create your own font and export to various formats. It sounds like you already have an idea of how to go about it. Best of luck.

Comment: @rawnewdlz Can you suggest online or for linux services?

Comment: Does the font license permit you to subset or alter the font?

Comment: @PeterConstable yes, also they are only 2 character.They are not so unique

Comment: How many or how unique isn’t important. The font license is what matters. Have you tried searching “font subsetter”?

Answer (score 1):

---

Fonttools looks like a good option in Python: https://github.com/fonttools/fonttools

A Node.js one: https://github.com/foliojs/fontkit claims usage:

```
var fontkit = require('fontkit');

// open a font synchronously
var font = fontkit.openSync('font.ttf');

// layout a string, using default shaping features.
// returns a GlyphRun, describing glyphs and positions.
var run = font.layout('hello world!');

// create a font subset
var subset = font.createSubset();
run.glyphs.forEach(function(glyph) {
  subset.includeGlyph(glyph);
});

subset.encodeStream()
      .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('subset.ttf'));
```

TODO learn how to use it icon fonts like font awesome. You can get the Unicode character used for each glyph easily from their website: https://fontawesome.com/icons/comment?s=regular but also of course form distro files, e.g. `npm install --save-dev fontawesome-free@1.0.4` we see at node_modules/fontawesome-free/css/all.css

```
.fa-comment:before {
  content: "\f075"; }
```

I tried somthing along:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const fontkit = require('fontkit');

const EXT = '.woff2'

const glyphs = {
  'fa-solid-900': [
    '\u{f03a}',
    '\u{f042}',
    '\u{f062}',
    '\u{f0c1}',
    '\u{f111}',
    '\u{f02c}',
  ],
  'fa-regular-400': [
    '\u{f075}',
  ],
  'fa-brands-400': [
    '\u{f266}',
  ],
}

for (const fontname in glyphs) {
  const font_basename = fontname + EXT
  const font = fontkit.openSync(path.join('node_modules', 'fontawesome-free', 'webfonts', font_basename));
  const subset = font.createSubset();
  for (const glyph of font.glyphsForString(glyphs[fontname].join(''))) {
    subset.includeGlyph(glyph);
  }
  subset.encodeStream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(path.join('dist', font_basename)));
}
```

and it did produce e.g. `fa-solid-900.woff2`, but that font file did not work for me for some reason, the glyphs weren't showing. Also it was much larger than the original font file, at 405K rather than 77K for the original. Tested at:

```
    "fontawesome-free": "1.0.4",
    "fontkit": "1.8.1",
```

Browser shows error:

> Failed to decode downloaded font: dist/fa-solid-900.woff2
> tmp.html#tmp-2:1
>
> OTS parsing error: hhea: misaligned table

The same happens when I try with the TTF versions.

Maybe also consider: https://github.com/omacranger/fontawesome-subset which auto extracts. But it doesn't auto extract the corresponding CSS as well it seems, just the fonts? Tested at `"fontawesome-subset": "3.0.0"`, I notice that that package requires building native dependencies which is a downside. Then I tried a hello world and that failed: https://github.com/omacranger/fontawesome-subset/issues/16#issuecomment-1046822754

Comment: For your purpose, you can try [subset-iconfont](https://www.npmjs.com/package/subset-iconfont). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72799475/3437454.

Answer (score 0):

A Web search will quickly provide options, such as this: https://www.afasterweb.com/2018/03/09/subsetting-fonts-with-glyphhanger/

Answer (score 0):

If single characters, you can have a try with [subset-font](https://github.com/papandreou/subset-font).